# Why unregisterReceiver() never calls onServiceDisconnected?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I bind to a Service in my Activity:

```
override fun onStart() {
    Timber.d("onStart")
    super.onStart()
    val intent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
    bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
}
```

which works so far. Then the `bindService()` calls `onServiceConnected()`:

```
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()  */
private val serviceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {

    override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName,
                                    service: IBinder) {
        // We've bound to MyService, cast the IBinder and get MyService instance
        val binder = service as MyService.MyBinder
        myService = binder.service
        isBound = true
        registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter)
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
        myService!!.removeRecevier(this@MainActivity)
        isBound = false
        unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver)
    }
}
```

In my `onStop()` I also have `unbindService(serviceConnection)` , but here the onServiceDisconnected() is never triggered? **What am I doing wrong?**

Therefore I get:

```html
Activity MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver@68091a2 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.MyBroadcastReceiver@68091a2 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Comment: what do you need `myBroadcastReceiver` for? why do you want to register it after binding to your service?

Comment: That service has nothing to do with the recevier, I need both. I just wrote it because of the error message.

Comment: so register it in `onStart` and unregister in `onStop` (or `onCreate` / `onDestroy`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the purpose of [`onServiceDisconnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected(android.content.ComponentName))

> Called when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically happens when the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed. This does not remove the ServiceConnection itself -- this binding to the service will remain active, and you will receive a call to `onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder)` when the Service is next running.

So this is actually only called, whenever you loose a connection to the actual service. When you unbind from the service, you have to do the cleanup manually. Better handle the receiver on a different (other) level than the `ServiceConnection` - like `onStart()`/`onStop()`.